# Notice with $category->getProducts() : "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to get total number of products in one category in Prestashop, I get the correct number but with this notice:

> "Trying to get property of non-object in Category.php".

Here is my code :

```
<?php
define('PRESTASHOP_S_EXTERNAL_SCRIPT', true);
include(dirname(__FILE__).'\..\prestashop_1.6.1.0\prestashop\config\config.inc.php');

//returns 1
echo Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

$id_category = 123;

$category = new Category($id_category, (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'),(int)Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DEFAULT'));

//works
echo $category->getName();

//returns 1   
echo is_object($category);

//returns the correct number but with a PHP notice ("Trying to get property of non-object in Category.php on line 671")
echo $category->getProducts(1,1,1000,null,null,1,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notice is thrown because you don't have any Controller set in your Context.

If you look at Category.php on line 671:

```
public function getProducts($id_lang, $p, $n, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, $get_total = false, $active = true, $random = false, $random_number_products = 1, $check_access = true, Context $context = null)
{
    // [...]
    $front = in_array($context->controller->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront'));
    // [...]
}
```

The problem comes from this code `$context->controller->controller_type`. There's no Controller defined in your context because you're not running your script from within Prestashop.

You can try to manually add a Controller to the Context object:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->controller = new FrontController();
echo $category->getProducts(1,1,1000,null,null,1,1);
```

Comment: I added :

`$context = Context::getContext();
$context->controller = new Controller();`

The last line gives me a Fatal error **Cannot instantiate abstract class Controller**.

Comment: My bad, try with `AdminController` instead.

Comment: AdminController throws a couple of errors but FrontController works fine.
So the code is :
`$context = Context::getContext();
$context->controller = new FrontController();`